# Pushing array but i needed no quotes

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

i have problem when im using array into my render apps..

here my code for getting list chat from sqlite..

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  const listchat = [];
  this.initDB()
    .then(db => {
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'SELECT num, text, type, _id,user FROM chat where CAST(user as INT) order by num desc',
          [],
        ).then(([tx, results]) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            let row = results.rows.item(i);
            var user = {id: 2, avatar: null};
            const {num, text, type, _id} = row;
            listchat.push({
              num,
              text,
              type,
              _id,
              user,
            });
          }
          resolve(listchat);
        });
      })
        .then(result => {
          this.closeDatabase(db);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
});
```

and i got results from query like this :

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "6d357f55-5fb8-4fec-ac5f-26cc1df4b98d",
    "num": 1,
    "text": "here must number 111111111111111111",
    "type": null,
    "user": {
      "avatar": null,
      "_id": 2
    }
  }
]
```

and what i need is no quotes on *"avatar and id"*

```
    [
  {
    "_id": "6d357f55-5fb8-4fec-ac5f-26cc1df4b98d",
    "num": 1,
    "text": "here must number 111111111111111111",
    "type": null,
    "user": {
      avatar: null,
      _id: 2
    }
  }
]
```

the problem is on quotes.. someone have solution for this ?

Comment: This is a formatting issue. Both are valid javascript. Only the top one (with quotes) is valid JSON.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you are outputting the object, and you don't explain why you need to have no quotes, so we can't help you. But the object you want is the same as the object you want. Please explain why you want no quotes

Comment: @CodeBling using gifted-chat for react native . https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/

Comment: If you want it to be JSON, you need it to look like the top one.  If you are consuming it is a javascript you reference it as the bottom.  Either way acceptable, so im not sure what youre desired endstate is really.

Comment: @Goroka You should put that in the question, along with the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Goroka are you using `JSON.stringify` to see the `listchat` result? There is no difference of having a property name with string type or directly.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to remove quotes from the query results. The object that you have posted in your question is completely valid for `react-native-gifted-chat`. Please update your question with more information.